# datetime conversion with specific format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

i want to filter the data from a datatable using dataview row filter Datatable having the column name month having like this "01-04-2012 00:00:00". I want to get the get the data using this format..

This is my partial code

```
     dv1 = dtable.DefaultView;
            DateTime start = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 1,0,0,0);

            dv1.RowFilter =Convert.ToString(start); //"Month = '04-01-2011 00:00:00'";
```

it returns the following error : Syntax error: Missing operand after '00' operator. I can't able to fix this error please help me to do this ...

Comment: Ref this Post : 
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928660/convert-different-format-of-datetime-to-specific-string-format#comment17551801_12928660

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose the datetime value into `#`. You also have to say what column you want to compare with this value.

For example:

```
dv1.RowFilter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                "Date = #{0}#", start);
```

(where `Date` is the actual name of your datetime-column)

- [DataView.RowFilter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx)
- [Using the InvariantCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, you are missing the name of the column you would want to filter on.

For example:
`dv1.RowFilter = string.Format("PurchaseDate = '{0}'", Convert.ToString(start));`

The assumption is that PurchaseDate is the date inside the view, the data is to be filtered using.