# Convert different format of DateTime to specific String format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime, datetime-format

Im Getting  `System.datetime.now` from different Machine .Each system having different datetime format as a mension below

```
16-Oct-12 7:25:22 PM
16/10/2012 7:10:47 PM [DD/MM/YYYY]
10/16/2012 7:10:51 PM [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

How To convert Different format of `DateTime` to specific String format ?

```
string sDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: sounds like you are using string to "transport" the datetime from other machines. Can't you simply use a DateTime object and only format it to a String using the code provided by yourself when actually displaying the date?

Comment: Do you *know* the format of each string you get? If not, how can you possibly expect to work out what (say) "10/11/2012 7:10:47 PM" would mean? Is that October 11th or November 10th?

Comment: (If you're in control of both machines, you simply need to avoid using different formats... the point of different cultures giving different formats is for *user presentation*, not machine to machine communication.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (DateTime.TryParse(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"), out result))
                    sDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
                else
                {
                    if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Equals("dd-MMM-yy")) sDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
                    else sDateTime = DateTime.Now.Month +"/" + DateTime.Now.Day+ "/" + DateTime.Now.Year + " " +  DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

First result of Google search: [Custom datetime format strings from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

You have to use the line of code you provided explicitly on the other machines when returning the datetime:

```
string sDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");]
```

This is however not aware of time zones! If your application spans several time zones, you should take that into count too!

Or, even better, you could return the Unix time (milliseconds from 1970-01-01) as a long, and of course the timezone info too, if that is different across the machines... (Beware, .NET expoch time is from 0001-01-01 though!)

[Returning Epoch time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c)

- I would recommend **against** using tryParse: You can not reliably determine if a date is in `[DD/MM/YYYY]` or `[MM/DD/YYYY]`, only when the month of day is greater than 12... And this would lead to mysterious errors. Believe me, been there, done that (the debugging part)...

Answer (score 0):

try the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) methode of the Datetime class

Examples from the link:

```
string[] dateStrings = {"05/01/2009 14:57:32.8", "2009-05-01 14:57:32.8", 
                        "2009-05-01T14:57:32.8375298-04:00", 
                        "5/01/2008 14:57:32.80 -07:00", 
                        "1 May 2008 2:57:32.8 PM", "16-05-2009 1:00:32 PM", 
                        "Fri, 15 May 2009 20:10:57 GMT" };
DateTime dateValue;

Console.WriteLine("Attempting to parse strings using {0} culture.", 
                  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
{
   if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)) 
      Console.WriteLine("  Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, 
                        dateValue, dateValue.Kind);
   else
      Console.WriteLine("  Unable to parse '{0}'.", dateString);
}
```

Notice that in the example its not working for all given strings dates

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your example is the last two formats `16/10/2012 7:10:47 PM [DD/MM/YYYY]` and `10/16/2012 7:10:51 PM [MM/DD/YYYY]`. If the value is `10/11/2012 7:20:10 PM` how can you know that it is Oct 11, 2012 or Nov 10, 2012?

```
var input = new string []{ "16-Oct-12 7:25:22 PM",
                "16/10/2012 7:10:47 PM",
                "10/16/2012 7:10:51 PM"};

foreach (var date in input)
{
    var result = DateTime.MinValue;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Date value: {0}", result);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot parse value {0}", date);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `"16/10/2012 7:10:47 PM"` could not be parse.